# Display json array data through List in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

**My C# Class**

```
public class City
{

   public int City_id { get; set; }

    public string City_name { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public City[] lstCitiesResult { get; set; }
}
```

My Code:

```
namespace gtp2
{
  ....
  List<Model> li = new List<Model>();

  WebClient re = new WebClient();

  var data = re.DownloadString("url");

  var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(data);


  Response.Write(a.lstCitiesResult.ToString());
  ....
}
```

In **Response.Write** i got like this:gtp2.City[] Any Ideya?thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the result is an array of `City` so you need to loop through it. But you can have it displayed with a control that handles collection e.g. ListView, DataList etc. Try this:

```
string output = "";
foreach(var c in a.lstCitiesResult)
{
   output = output + String.Format("id: {0}, name: {1}", c.City_id, c.City_name);
}

Response.Write(output);
```